# Get value between square brackets by preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a string

```
$att = 'Size,9 x 8.5[=11.25],10 x 9.5[=15.5]'
```

I want to get values between square brackets: 11.25 and 15.5
I tried with preg_match

```
preg_match('/\[=(.*?)\]/', $att, $matches);
```

It only gets first value: 11.25
Is there something wrong?

Comment: Try `/\[[^]]+\]/g` ;).

Comment: You only need to use `preg_match_all` to obtain several results. Your pattern is correct.

Comment: @shA.t: There is no `g` modifier for `preg_match`

Comment: `g` modifier means `preg_match_all` ;).